# GoAccess: empty html report generated

Tags: apache, goaccess

When trying to create an html report of an Apache logfile wit [GoAccess](https://goaccess.io/), an empty html is generated. The html output code however, is shown in the console.

```
$sudo goaccess -f /var/log/apache2/access.log -o /var/www/report.html
$sudo goaccess -f /var/log/apache2/access.log -o /var/www/report.html -real-time-html
```

Both commands show the html code in the console but result in an empty file.

```
395096    0 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root     root           0 Sep 28 22:50 report.html
```

Comment: Are you on the latest version?

Comment: Apparently version 0.8.3

Comment: You want to use `>` instead of `-o`. Looks like `-o` was introduced in [v1.0](https://github.com/allinurl/goaccess/blob/master/ChangeLog#L32) Try `goaccess -f /var/log/apache2/access.log > /var/www/report.html` OR even better, upgrade to v1.0.2

Comment: `goaccess -f /var/log/apache2/access.log > /var/www/report.html` didn't do the job, tried it before. But upgrading to v1.0.2 did the trick.